# How to approach use of environment variables for Lambda@Edge

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm building Lambda function for CloudFront which checks if request has cookies, if not then forwards to login page. I need to customize response header `location` based on environment - for each env that will be different.

Initially I tried with environment variables but I got an error during deployment:
`InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation: The function cannot have environment variables`
So I switched to use `aws-sdk` with SSM `ssm.getParameter` but after zipping lambda archive with `aws-sdk` and one more depedency it's around 13 MB. The limit for Lambda@Edge functions is 1 MB.

I'm wondering would be the best way to approach that. Generate file with environment variables on each Lambda build and require it in `index.js`?

Comment: Have you tried using [custom origin headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101487/10692493)?

Comment: My problem requires `viewer-request` event type

Comment: What is this "one more depedency "? Is it greater than 1MB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use SSM but don't include AWS SDK in your Lambda function.** [Lambda documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html#w491aac27c21) says that the AWS SDK is included in the Lambda runtime.

To test this, I created a new Node.js 12 Lambda function from scratch in the Lambda console & replaced its existing code with this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const SSM = new AWS.SSM();
exports.handler = async() => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: await SSM.getParameter({ Name: 'my-param' }).promise(),
    };
};
```

**This works!** Downloading the deployment package of this function from the Lambda console showed that it's just 276 bytes in size. I then deployed this to Lambda@Edge & **that worked too!**